# Powershell Forms Progressbar not updated correctly

Tags: powershell

I have a piece of PowerShell code that shows the progress. The progress bar is not updated correctly. It starts with 0% but it should start with for example 17%. Also, when it is finished, the progress bar is not finished. So the layout is not 100% accurate.

[The progress bar has not the correct length.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/In6cW.png)

What is wrong with the code?

```
# =============================================================================================================================================
# Add assemblies.
# =============================================================================================================================================

  Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

# =============================================================================================================================================
# Define objects
# =============================================================================================================================================

  $frmTest                        = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Form'
  $pgbProgress                    = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar'
  $lblPackage                     = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Label'

# =============================================================================================================================================
# Form and show the progressbar. Close with the 'X' at the upper right corner.
# =============================================================================================================================================

  $frmTest.Controls.Add($pgbProgress)
  $frmTest.Controls.Add($lblPackage)
  $frmTest.AutoScaleDimensions    = New-Object System.Drawing.SizeF(6, 13)
  $frmTest.AutoScaleMode          = 'Font'
  $frmTest.ClientSize             = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(528, 220)
  $frmTest.Name = 'frmTest'
  $frmTest.Text = 'Form'
  $frmTest.add_Shown({
                      $arrPackages  = @("IrfanView","7Zip","WinZIP","Office","PhotoShop","PaintShop")
                      $numPackages  = $arrPackages.Count
                      $numCounter   = 1
                      ForEach($Package in $arrPackages)
                       {
                        [int]$Percentage    = ($numCounter / $numPackages) * 100
                        $lblPackage.Text    = "Processing: $Package   ($numCounter of $numPackages packages - $Percentage%"
                        $pgbProgress.Value  = $Percentage
                        $pgbProgress.PerformStep()
                        Sleep -Seconds 4
                        $numCounter++
                       }
                      Sleep -Seconds 5
                      [void]$frmTest.Close()
                      [void]$frmTest.Dispose()
                     })

  $pgbProgress.Location           = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(13, 165)
  $pgbProgress.Name               = 'pgbProgress'
  $pgbProgress.Size               = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(503, 43)
  $pgbProgress.Style              = 'Continuous'
  
  $lblPackage.AutoSize            = $True
  $lblPackage.Location            = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(13, 137)
  $lblPackage.Name                = 'lblPackage'
  $lblPackage.Size                = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(38, 13)
  $lblPackage.Text                = 'Processing all the packages...'

  [void]$frmTest.ShowDialog()
```

Any help is appreciated.

With kind regards,
Willem-Jan

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you using? I can't recreate on Windows PowerShell 5.1. Looks good to me.

Comment: Also runs okay on PowerShell 7.1.3, but maybe you have an issue with the sizing of the progress bar. It gets quite full for the percentage described i.e. 83% is more than that.

Comment: perfectly works on PowerShell 5.1 

Change to  Start-Sleep -Seconds 4

Comment: @Ash: I have version 5.1. The problem occurs with PowerShell ISE. But I has some strange behavior with a regular PowerShell: at one point the progress bar flipped back. And the label is not updated.

Comment: @TheStingPilot, try my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I think Windows Forms is a little flaky, but despite my comment above, it seems to be more reliable if you don't set the value, but set the [Step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.progressbar.step?view=net-5.0) instead, because you are moving the bar a set figure each time. This then uses `PerformStep()` to increase the bar. Doing both i.e. setting the value and using `PerformStep()` was confusing matters.

Like this:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

$frmTest = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Form'
$pgbProgress = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar'
$lblPackage = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Label'

$frmTest.Controls.Add($pgbProgress)
$frmTest.Controls.Add($lblPackage)
$frmTest.AutoScaleDimensions = New-Object System.Drawing.SizeF(6, 13)
$frmTest.AutoScaleMode = 'Font'
$frmTest.ClientSize = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(528, 220)
$frmTest.Name = 'frmTest'
$frmTest.Text = 'Form'
$frmTest.add_Shown( {
        $arrPackages = @("IrfanView", "7Zip", "WinZIP", "Office", "PhotoShop", "PaintShop")
        $numPackages = $arrPackages.Count
        $numCounter = 1
        # Set the step value.
        $pgbProgress.Step = ($numCounter / $numPackages) * 100
        ForEach ($Package in $arrPackages) {
            [int]$Percentage = ($numCounter / $numPackages) * 100
            $lblPackage.Text = "Processing: $Package   ($numCounter of $numPackages packages - $Percentage%"
            $pgbProgress.PerformStep()
            Sleep -Seconds 2
            $numCounter++
        }
        Sleep -Seconds 2
        [void]$frmTest.Close()
        [void]$frmTest.Dispose()
    })

$pgbProgress.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(13, 165)
$pgbProgress.Name = 'pgbProgress'
$pgbProgress.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(503, 43)
$pgbProgress.Style = 'Continuous'
  
$lblPackage.AutoSize = $True
$lblPackage.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(13, 137)
$lblPackage.Name = 'lblPackage'
$lblPackage.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(38, 13)
$lblPackage.Text = 'Processing all the packages...'

[void]$frmTest.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: many thanks, that solved the problem indeed. In some cases however, the formatting of the text label is a little bit mangled.

Comment: Glad to help. I think that's the GUI rather than the code unfortunately. I have seen it not keep up sometimes. I'd recommend moving over to [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/powershell) rather than the using the ISE these days too.

Comment: I tried to add a "Cancel" button to interrupt the operation progress (the ForEach loop) but it's impossible to click it, despite being enabled. Any ideas how to implement such thing?

Comment: I think this would require creating another PowerShell runspace and stopping it if the cancel button was clicked, as Forms freeze when they are running a task in the process. The only other way I can think of would be to run the tasks that you are doing asynchronously and have the task check for the cancellationToken, which probably wouldn't be best done in PowerShell. Ask a new question about it, perhaps someone will be able to help.